# How to include cookies while using autorest generated typescript client?

Tags: typescript, cookies, autorest

I am using [AutoRest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest) to generate Typescript client for RESTful API based on OpenAPI spec file like this:

```
autorest --typescript --use-internal-constructors --override-client-name=MyApiClient --input-file=API.Swagger.json --namespace=MyApi.Client --typescript.output-folder=C:\One\ts --add-credentials=true
```

When I make a call using generated API client over CORS it doesn't include any of the Cookies.

JavaScript `fetch` provides this construct to include cookies:

```
fetch(uri, { credentials: 'include' })
```

But I could not figure a way to make it happen with the AutoRest generated API client. I did look through `msRest.ts` to see if I can use any of the available Credentials types.

[Update]:

After digging further I figured options parameter to the client has a property `withCredentials` which can be set to true. Eventually, `node_modules\@azure\ms-rest-js\es\lib\xhrHttpClient.js` makes the API call. Specifically, this line makes the call:

```
xhr.send(request.body === undefined ? null : request.body);
```

I debugged thorough and made sure that `withCredentials` is set to `true` but for some reason it doesn't send the cookies! If I make a call using javascript `fetch` it sends cookies and autorest generated client doesn't send cookies!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator), which supports both OpenAPI/Swagger v2 and v3. (Only OpenAPI specification v3 supports the cookie parameter).

I remember we've added cookie parameters support to the TypeScript generators. Please open a [ticket/issue](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new) if you need help from the OpenAPI Generator community.

Comment: not sure if I can use OpenAPI generator as all our current build systems are tied to AutoRest. I will have a look.